# How to load layers from postgres using SELECT statement?

Tags: qgis, postgresql, pyqgis

I am trying to load a postgres table (columns extracted using a select statement) from the python console in QGis:

The following works fine and the layer loads as expected:

```
uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
uri.setConnection("*****","***","****","****","*****")
uri.setDataSource("","mytable","geom","","id")
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(),"LayerName","postgres")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)

if not vlayer.isValid():
    print "layer failed to load"
```

However, if I swap out the table name for an SQL select statement:

```
sql = "(select id from mytable)"
uri.setDataSource("",sql,"geom","","id")
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(),"LayerName","postgres")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)

if not vlayer.isValid():
    print "layer failed to load"
```

Then the layer fails to load.

Also, if I use a very long SQL statement to try to select more columns, I get a message in the terminal window along the lines of:

> NOTICE: identifier "(lonq sql text here)" will be truncated to"

Am I missing something? I am using QGis 2.4.

Answer (score 2):

You missed the `geom` column in your SQL query!

So, if I rewrite the `sql` string to:

```
sql = "(select id, geom from mytable)"
```

it works for me...