# QgsDataSourceuRI and left outer join

Tags: qgis, postgresql, pyqgis, psycopg2

I'm trying to load data from different tables using left outer joins into a QgsVectorLayer. The approach I'm following so far is the one from the developers cookbook [here](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadlayer.html). The underlying database is postgres. The query returns correct data, including a geometry column, however I can't figure out how to get the join inside the query to work with [QgsDataSourceUri.setDataSource()](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsDataSourceURI.html#aedf47ddf31b03af376a5c35ca2b17a54). As the table the data come from needs to be specified, is it even possible to do so?

Would approaching the problem using psycopg2 be more suited, and if so, is there a way to create a layer from the result set? The only way I can think of is creating an empty layer and adding each feature individually by looping over the result set. But possibly there is an easier way?

Sadly, using the builtin DB Manager is not an option. The layer has to be added programmatically.

Comment: Are your query(s) static enough that you can setup views on the database side?

Comment: The queries are pretty static, but I cannot setup views as I have read-only access, the idea is aweseome though. I have asked the "DBA" about it, he told me that setting up views is not going to happen...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to set up the `QgsDataSourceURI` like in [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/162409/how-to-load-layers-from-postgres-using-select-statement/197749#197749):

```
uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
uri.setConnection('host', 'port', 'database', 'username', 'password')
sql = 'SELECT * FROM myschema.mytable JOIN othertable USING(id)'
uri.setDataSource('', '(' + sql + ')', 'geom', '', 'id')

vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), 'LayerName','postgres')
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)

print('Is layer valid?', vlayer.isValid())
```

whereby, it's crucial that the SQL query has to be surrounded by brackets and at least `geom` and `id` columns are selected! Another important thing is, to leave the `schema` string in `setDataSource` empty and instead use it in the query.

**Update for PyQGIS 3:**

```py
uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
uri.setConnection('host', 'port', 'database', 'username', 'password')
sql = 'SELECT * FROM myschema.mytable JOIN othertable USING(id)'
uri.setDataSource('', '(' + sql + ')', 'geom', '', 'id')

vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), 'LayerName','postgres')
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)

print('Is layer valid?', vlayer.isValid())
```