# Select and load polygons intersecting another with PyQGIS (polygons stored in PostGIS)

Tags: qgis, postgis, pyqgis, qgis-2

I'm still a newbie at Python and I'm having issues selecting and loading polygons intersecting others with PyQGIS.

I managed to use PyQGIS to achieve that operation with shapefiles stored in my laptop but I haven't found a solution to proceed the same treatment on shapefiles stored in PostGIS.

This is what I came to so far :

```
from qgis.core import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import QSettings
from PyQt4.QtCore import QSettings
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer, QgsDataSourceURI
import processing

uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
uri.setConnection("localhost", "5432", "name of my database", "my user name", "my password")
uri.setDataSource("database schema", "table name", "geom")
couche = "PM"
layer1 = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), couche, "postgres")
if not layer1.isValid:
    print ('Chargement de la couche: echec !')
else:
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer1)


uri.setDataSource("database schema", "table name2", "geom")
couche = "batiments"
layer2 = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), couche, "postgres" )

subset_layer2 = processing.runalg('qgis:extractbylocation', layer2,layer1,['intersects'],0.0,None)


uri.setDataSource("rbal", "parcelles", "geom")
couche = "parcelles"
layer3 = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), couche, "postgres" )

subset_layer3 = processing.runalg('qgis:extractbylocation', layer3,layer1,['intersects'],0.0,None)
```

When I run the code I don't get any error but the treatment is loading forever without returning any results...

---

**EDIT**:

With that script I've managed to select all the polygons contained in layer2 that intersect layer1 but I do have to load layer2 to do so.
Is there a way to select and load those intersecting polygons without loading the whole layer in the first place ?

```
uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
uri.setConnection("localhost", "5432", "name of my database", "my user name", "my password")
uri.setDataSource("database schema", "table name", "geom")
couche = "PM"
layer1 = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), couche, "postgres")
if not layer1.isValid:
    print ('Chargement de la couche: echec !')
else:
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer1)


uri.setDataSource("database schema", "table name2", "geom")
couche = "batiments"
layer2 = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), couche, "postgres" )
if not layer2.isValid:
    print ('Chargement de la couche: echec !')
else:
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer2)

feats_layer1 = layer1.getFeatures()
for feat in feats_layer1:
    geom_layer1 = feat.geometry()
feats_layer2 = layer2.getFeatures()

for feature in feats_layer2:
    if feature.geometry().intersects(geom_layer1):
        layer2.select(feature.id())
```

Comment: Hi Bera, 
Yes it's exactly what I'm looking for but unfortunately I shall use pyqgis to do so (if there is a way to do so of course)

Comment: That's why I thought of importing my layers from PostGIS (script in my question) before using ```qgis:extractbylocation``` but it doesn't work

Comment: It has to be ```uri = QgsDataSourceURI()``` in QGIS 2.14 :/
But do you mean my script works in QGIS 3.16 once ```uri = QgsDataSourceURI()``` is replaced by ```uri=QgsDataSourceUri()``` ?

Comment: If you use QGIS 3.*x*, don't use PyQt4 ! Convert it into `PyQt5` or `qgis.PyQt.QtCore`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply J.Monticolo but I have to work with QGIS 2.*x* :)

Comment: Ok ..., but if you can, I advise you to upgrade to QGIS 3.*x*. You can develop using Python3, it's better for maintenance, Python2 is deprecated. And take benefits for all great and powerfull new features of QGIS 3 ... Do you have a difficult blockage for stay in 2.*x* ?

Comment: I agree with you but my company is not willing to upgrade to QGIS 3.*x* yet :/

Comment: have you tried simply using SQL to get the data back? since both layer are stored in PostGIS, you can do a simple query like explained [here](http://bostongis.com/postgis_intersection_intersects.snippet)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to J.Monticolo I've found an existing solution on stackoverflow:

[PyQGIS - Load a PostgreSQL/PostGIS layer from a SQL query](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/348839/162856)

[QgsDataSourceuRI and left outer join](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/195957/qgsdatasourceuri-and-left-outer-join)

**EDIT**:

Even though the links above provide (in my example) the best solution, there is a way to do the same thing only with PyQGIS:

```
from qgis.core import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import QSettings
from PyQt4.QtCore import QSettings
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer, QgsDataSourceURI
from qgis.gui import QgsMapCanvas
import processing

uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
uri.setConnection("localhost", "5432", "name of my database", "my user name", "my password")
uri.setDataSource("database schema", "table name", "geom")
couche = "PM"
layer1 = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), couche, "postgres")
if not layer1.isValid:
    print ('Chargement de la couche: echec !')
else:
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer1)


uri.setDataSource("database schema", "table name2", "geom")
couche = "batiments"
layer2 = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), couche, "postgres" )
if not layer2.isValid:
    print ('Chargement de la couche: echec !')
else:
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer2)

inter_feats = []

feats_layer1 = layer1.getFeatures()
for feat in feats_layer1:
    geom_layer1 = feat.geometry()
feats_layer2 = layer2.getFeatures()

for feature in feats_layer2:
    if feature.geometry().intersects(geom_layer1):
        inter_feats.append(feature.id())
        
layer2.select(inter_feats)

intersecting_features = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer2, 'C:/Users/Users/Documents/test.shp', "utf-8",  None, "ESRI Shapefile", onlySelected=True)


bati = QgsVectorLayer('C:/Users/Users/Documents/test.shp', "test", "ogr")
if not bat.isValid():
    print("Impossible de charger la couche !")

# add layer to the registry
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(bati)
```

Comment: but the "more" PyQGIS solution needs to load the two whole layers into QGIS and after do the intersection. If your layers contains thousands of records, this isn't the best performance solution !

Comment: I completely agree ! :)