# SQL Filter WFS layer in QGIS does not work

Tags: qgis, wfs

I added a layer via python

```
from qgis.core import QgsDataSourceUri, QgsVectorLayer, QgsProject

dsu = QgsDataSourceUri()
dsu.setParam( 'url', 'https://wfs-example-service/a/b/c/wfs' )
dsu.setParam( 'version', '2.0.0' )
dsu.setParam( 'typename', 'Flurstueck')
dsu.setParam( 'maxNumFeatures', '10000')
dsu.setParam( 'srsname', 'EPSG:25833')
dsu.setParam( 'pageSize', '2000')
dsu.setSql('SELECT * FROM Flurstueck WHERE st_intersects(Flurstueck.geometry, \'SRID=25833;POINT(-43.23456 72.4567772)\')')


layer = QgsVectorLayer( dsu.uri(), "Test Layer", "WFS" )
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```

The error message is

```
Column 'Flurstueck.geometry' references a non existing field
```

Indeed, the field is not in the response, but i hope, it should at least be usable in the SQL query. If not, how it can be filtered else?

How to retrieve data only by given points. Or even better: How to retrieve data that intersects with points from another layer?

Unfortunately, this really lacks of documentation.

Why this is not working? How to select the geoemtry from wfs, so that i can only select the one within the point(s)???

Comment: related https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/197800/276 similar concept.

Comment: also related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/427910/adding-spatial-filter-to-wfs-layer-request-not-working

Comment: it seems like "geom" instead of "geometry" is also not available ... i guess, the sql will be translated into a WFS-compatible request, correct?

Comment: Do a DescribeFeatureType request to discover the attributes of the FeatureType

Comment: When you say it lacks documentation, I assume you mean the QGIS Python API and not the WFS filter encoding standards ~ https://www.ogc.org/standard/filter/ or WFS standards ~ https://www.ogc.org/standard/wfs/

Comment: and finally, your point location seems to be in decimal degrees whilst EPSG:25833 is expecting metres ~ https://epsg.org/crs_25833/ETRS89-UTM-zone-33N.html